# How to create a map of a certain area of Mars?

Tags: mars, mapping

I am trying to create a personalised Google Maps style map of a certain portion of Mars! that will show three specific locations. Namely (a) Gale Crater (b) Hebrus Valles and (c) Valles Marineris.

At https://www.google.co.in/mars/ I can locate all three quite easily using the search feature but at any point in time I can show ONLY one of these location. What I want to do is to show ALL three simultaenously on the same map but cannot do so.

I have also tried going to [https://www.google.com/maps/space/mars](https://www.google.com/maps/space/mars/@0,88.367639,22963938m/data=!3m1!1e3) but could not find the search feature to show these three locations.

If I can see all three locations with the balloon markers simultaenously, I can take a screen-shot and create the map I am looking for.

Would be grateful if someone could help me create this map, or give me some pointers on how I could do this?

Comment: Welcome to *Space!*  You might get better results asking this question on gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you download google earth pro for free, you can also use it as a 3D google mars. There you can create a moving camera, going from one location to the next. This is not an answer to your question, but maybe a viable alternative to what you're trying to do.

Comment: There should be large format images of Mars downloadable from somewhere in NASA, you could paste markers there yourself, if that't okay for your application. I haven't tried this but it might also work: https://mars.nasa.gov/maps/explore-mars-map/fullscreen/

Comment: @uhoh -- your solution can be made to work. thanks for the link

Comment: @Calcutta oh that's great news! If it does work well for your, then please leave a short answer mentioning that. It is always okay and welcome to post an answer to your own question, and that helps future readers who find your question while searching. Other people may also leave different answers as well.

Answer (score 2):

As advised by @uhoh we can visit the site mentioned in his comment [mars.nasa.gov/maps/explore-mars-map/fullscreen](https://mars.nasa.gov/maps/explore-mars-map/fullscreen) go through the tutorial, search for and locate the areographic features and place balloon markers on the same. Worked for me.

Comment: I recommend you download Google Earth pro. It's free and contains lots of advanced mapping features and allows you to place multiple "pins" draw lines, highlight areas and much more.